# Detecting GooglePlayServices availability does not work

Tags: android, google-play-services, chromecast, google-cast

**UPDATE: Probably fixed in GPS v12 but some people still report that nothing has changed. See [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65359941) on google issue tracker.**

I have encountered a problem with detecting Google Play Services availability.
I enable GoogleCast feature in my app when user has proper PlayServices version installed.

I check PS availability in the following way:

```
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(applicationContext) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS
```

However, users which are identified as having PS installed don't really have it.
They are getting app crashes during cast initialization. 
There are few different cast-related app crashes causes:

1. Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Remote load failed. No local fallback found.
2. Caused by com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Remote load failed. No local fallback found.
3. Caused by com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: Failed to get module context
4. Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.

All of these crashes occurs while initializing MediaRouteButton.
I have searched a lot to figure out what can be wrong and I've found only that PlayServices are not up to date.

It happens on both rooted and non-rooted devices.

Has anyone met with similar problem?

Comment: Same problem in my apps. On some devices work ok, on some has same errors.For the moment I have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I also detect same crash on my crashlytics report, going from less than 10 hits by day to more than 900 hits on specific dates.
Those dates corresponding to Play Services update release days. So I suppose that happens when Play Services is updating on device, version check availability is ok and method return SUCCESS but module seems not available at this moment. I found no solution to solve that problem.

Comment: See this comment https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65359941#comment69